# OpenMP generates segfault in a code that uses Armadillo

Tags: c++, openmp, armadillo

First off, I am not very familiar with OpenMP. I would like to reduce the execution time of my C++ code, which involves a few hundred iterations of matrix diagonalization, using OpenMP. I am **not** trying to parallel each diagonalization (according to Armadillo's documentation that can be achieved by forcing Armadillo to use OpenBLAS library); rather, I want to distribute the load between threads on an 8-core machine.

There seem to be a problem with accessing memory as I get "segmentation fault". I wonder whether it is something that I am not doing right or the problem is due to the way Armadillo creates and manipulates matrices.

Here is a minimal code that captures the essence of the problem I have been having. The idea is to diagonalize, say, 1000 100x100 matrices and store their eigenvalues in a file.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>
#include <fstream>
#include<omp.h>         

int main()
{   
    std::ofstream  File;
    File.open("./RESULTS.dat");

    arma::mat M;   //THE MATRIX TO BE DIAGONALIZED
    arma::mat Eigenvecs;  //EIGENVECTORS
    arma::vec Eigenval;   //EIGENVALUES

    arma::mat RESULTS; //STORING EIGENVALUES TEMPORARILY 

    //DISTRIBUTING THE ITTERATIONS AMONG CORES USING OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel shared(RESULTS) private(M,Eigenvecs,Eigenval)
    {
    #pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(guided)
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++ )
    {
        M = arma::randu<arma::mat>(200,200); //CREATING A RANDOM MATRIX
        M = 0.5*(M + M.t() );  //TO GUARANTEE THAT THE M IS NORMAL

        arma::eig_sym( Eigenval , Eigenvecs , M ); //DIAGONALIZING "M"

        RESULTS = arma::join_vert(RESULTS,Eigenval.t()); //CONCATENATING EIGENVALUES TO THE MATRIX "RESULTS" 
    }
    }

    File << RESULTS;  //WRITING "RESULTS" TO THE FILE
    File.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it seems that the load is correctly distributed (I used htop to monitor the cores on the machine), but at the end I get "Segmentation fault".

Comment: What happens if you run it under a debugger?  Where does the segfault occur?

Comment: So, I'm fairly sure you *are* actually using some kind of BLAS+LAPACK library under the rugs: [without them, Armadillo cannot perform diagonalization](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#dependencies).  So then the question becomes: is the underlying BLAS+LAPACK library thread-safe?  That would very much depend on what kind of BLAS implementation you are using (e.g. OpenBLAS? MKL?) as well as how it's compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, although I don't know why this fixes the problem. Here is the modified code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<armadillo>
#include <fstream>
#include<omp.h> 


int main()
{   
    std::ofstream  File;
    File.open("./RESULTS.dat");

    arma::mat M;
    arma::mat RESULTS;
    arma::mat Eigenvecs;
    arma::vec Eigenval;

    int i,tid=0;

    //DISTRIBUTING THE ITTERATIONS AMONG CORES USING OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(guided) shared(RESULTS) private(M,Eigenvecs,Eigenval,tid)
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        M = arma::randu<arma::mat>(400,400);
        M = 0.5*(M + M.t() );
        //std::cout << M << std::endl;

        arma::eig_sym( Eigenval , Eigenvecs , M );

        #pragma omp ordered
        RESULTS = arma::join_vert(RESULTS,Eigenval.t());

        std::cout << i << " , " << tid  << " --- " << Eigenval(0) << std::endl;
    }

    File << RESULTS;   
    File.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than marking variables as private within the #pragma omp, it might be safer of to explicitly declare them within the loop.  This way you completely ensure that each thread gets its own variables (and hence memory) instead of relying on OpenMP (which may have some baroque rules as to what is private for non-trivial matrix objects)